# xcode8 project crash by xcode9 reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero running on ios11

Tags: ios, crash, xcode9

```
    2017-10-26 14:42:50.817301+0800 thememaker[32585:4041966] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework

2017-10-26 14:42:50.822148+0800 thememaker[32585:4041966] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-10-26 14:42:51.295291+0800 thememaker[32585:4041966] * Assertion failure in -[_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS _contentViewFittingHeight], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3694.4.18/_UINavigationBarVisualProviderModernIOS.m:544
2017-10-26 14:42:51.297238+0800 thememaker[32585:4041966] * Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Sigh. Contentview size is zero.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185e93d38 0x1853a8528 0x185e93c0c 0x186822c24 0x18fdf79cc 0x18fbf3518 0x18fdf9efc 0x18f5ae8f4 0x18f632ca4 0x18f632bac 0x18f333dfc 0x18f333c44 0x18f331de0 0x18f2a38a4 0x18f2a37d4 0x100b0b5ac 0x100b08f58 0x100b08c40 
0x18f82a8bc 0x18f9d3588 0x18f9d32c0 0x18f5abd8c 0x18f9d3588 0x18f9d32c0 
0x18fbf1774 0x18f9d3588 0x18f9d32c0 0x18f609ae4 0x18f82a8bc 0x18f9d3588 0x18f9d32c0 0x18f82a560 0x18f82ad00 0x18f9d3588 0x18f9d3700 0x18f9d32c0 
0x18f8298a0 0x18fba67f0 0x18f50c8dc 0x18f312cdc 0x18f50b5c0 0x18f799454 0x18fa691f0 0x18f7990b8 0x18f799928 0x18ff026e8 0x18ff0258c 0x18fc7e9c0 0x18fe13fc8 0x18fc7e870 0x18fa68850 0x18f509e28 0x18f90d6ec 0x188535768 
0x18853e070 0x1026f945c 0x102705b74 0x188569a04 0x1885696a8 0x188569c44 0x185e3c358 0x185e3c2d8 0x185e3bb60 0x185e39738 0x185d5a2d8 0x187bebf84 0x18f307880 0x100b5dccc 0x18587e56c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**running ios10 it's worked fine.

but running on ios11 crashed:(**

when I start app crashed and not execute didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
Any help on this ? thanks.

Comment: where are you facing this crash in code. Any method or when you start  app

Comment: thanks, before the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions fucntion crashed, I guess the problem is may be about storyboard ,but i don't find it.

Comment: not running didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: first you need to find location where app is crashed. set an All expetion breakpoint to find the problem Area.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/17802868/4970453

Comment: @jerry did you check this SO post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46369355/uinavigationcontroller-crashes-on-xcode-9

Comment: @Fabio Berger not this problem when I check that post

Comment: @Varinder Singh thanks a lot , I found the problem Area.I have SlideNavigationController(singletonInstance) Class, got error when Running ios11

Comment: @jerry How did you fix the issue? Facing somewhat same kind of issue :(

Comment: Me to faced same problem, i have changed something in view layer like (  self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
) and set that view controller in APPDELEGATE CLASS,  its crashing, so now i updated that code after the view completely present. now its working fine. if you are doing anything in UIView layer please do the  changes after controller completely present.

Comment: Please guide i am facing same issue how you fix this?